# Calculating the effects in a fractionating column

Tags: physical-chemistry, process-chemistry

Consider a fractionating column used to separate a mixture of acetone (A) and toluene (B) with a liquid molar composition of acetone called x. The feed is F, the distillate is D, the waste is W and the molar vaporation enthalpy is λ. How can one get an approximate difference between the effects in the boilar and condenser using only the given values for F, λ, x(F), x(D) and x(W)